# React Native or Flutter?

Tags: react-native, flutter, mobile-development

I currently learn React and I want to learn Mobile Development too. I do not want to learn Swift,Java or Kotlin. I want Flutter or React Native. Which one to choose and why?

Comment: Opinion based question. Please read the terms of use.

Comment: there are countless videos on this topic on YouTube.

Answer (score 3):

In you case React Native will be fast to learn. Flutter language is Dart and you will need to learn new language but as I understand you don’t want. Flutter is new then React Native. Flutter is growing fast but React native is more stabile and has a lot of helpful moduls.